# Return value to client has one decimal type value and alway has 6 decimal places

Tags: c#, webapi2

(the project I'm working is C# WebAPI 2 (.net 4.6.2))

in the model of responsing, the class has one field which is decimal type value as average value. And in client the field alway gets 6 decimal places like 123456.000000.

I've added a ToString() method and try following [JsonSerializer - serialize decimal places with 'N2' formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871720/jsonserializer-serialize-decimal-places-with-n2-formatting)
to create an CustomDecimalFormatConverter(see below), but seems NOT work at all. How could I do to make client get correct value with different decimal places of.
The format I need is {0:######.######}.

```
public class CustomDecimalFormatConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(decimal));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, object value,
                                   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(string.Format("{0:######.######}", value));
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
                                 object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

in the class has a ToString() method:

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, new CustomDecimalFormatConverter()).ToString();
    }
```

In webapi's controller, I use OK(ojbect) to return the object.