# How to serialize decimal as string?

Tags: json.net

As known it's better to use string format to serialize decimal number. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38357877/4805491

Many services send decimal values as strings and `Json.NET` deserializes it well.

But I can't find how to serialize decimal with string format?

Should I make custom `JsonConverter` for all decimal numbers? Or there are ways to do it with default `Json.NET` opportunities?

**Updated**

I need this test to be passed.

So, I need to replace all decimal values with string values when or after 
`JToken.FromObject( ... )` is called.

```
var json = await Client.RequestJsonAsync( desc, default );
var obj = json.ToObject<MyObject>();
var json2 = JToken.FromObject( obj );
Assert.IsTrue( JToken.DeepEquals( json, json2 ), "Jsons are not equal" );
```

Unfortunately there is no (or I can't find) method to all replace all nodes in hierarchy. `JToken.Replace` only replaces itself. Also I don't see a way to iterating within hierarchy.

Comment: Please see [Json.net serialize numeric properties as string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39526057).  The answer is specifically for `int`, just change it to `decimal` and you should be good. Also [Convert long number as string in the serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17369278) and [JsonSerializer - serialize decimal places with 'N2' formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17871720).  Do those answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static JToken FromObject(object obj) {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Converters.Add( new DecimalToStringConverter() );
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault( settings );
        return JToken.FromObject( obj, serializer );
    }


public class DecimalToStringConverter : JsonConverter {

    public override bool CanRead => false;
    public override bool CanWrite => true;


    public override bool CanConvert(Type type) {
        return type == typeof( decimal ) || type == typeof( decimal? );
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type type, object existingInstance, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object instance, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        var number = (decimal) instance;
        writer.WriteValue( number.ToString( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ) );
    }


}
```